# PHP . How to force my code to redirect after Post Method?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

When i execute `mydomaine/send` for `forward function` In controller, i got my redirection as expected to `THIS_URL`in form.

But using Vuejs, when i use axios, `THIS_URL`comes in console only and no redirection happens after POST Method form.

i would like to be redirected to the URL in output of this code :

```
 public function forward(Request $request){
      return view('view', ['data'=>$request]);
 }
```

View page :

```
<form id="redirectForm" action="<?php echo $_GET['THIS_URL']; ?>" method="post" name="myform">
</form>
```

The prob

Answer (score 0):

On your promise consumers, set the `window.location` to your desired redirect url as follows:

```
axios.post('your_post_url_here', {data: data})
    .then((response) => {
        //you can do it here
        window.location = "your_redirect_url_here";
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        //OR here
        window.location = "your_redirect_url_here";
    })
    .finally(() => {
        //OR here
        window.location = "your_redirect_url_here";
    });
```